# Recidive users with unsolvable questions

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

It happened to me more than a single time to see users asking questions which could only be answered with a *"Nope, what you're asking is impossible"*, generating comments and answers which try to explain the reason why the question just hasn't got an answer (other than "no"). The OP then ignores and refuses to accept these reasonings, keeping the question open and not willing to reformulate/delete it or even accept an answer. I've seen a situation like this several times, most frequently on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), but it obviously happens on other SE sites too.

The steps are almost always the same:

1. An user posts what looks like a normal question.
2. After a few comments or answers (or sometimes immediately), several users quickly come to the conclusion that the OP's problem cannot be solved, and the only answer is "no".
3. Now the situation splits in two:

   - In the first case, no valid answers are given, probably because the users don't feel good answering with a simple *"No"* without doing a long research to justify their reasoning (or maybe are fearing downvotes even though their answer would be correct).
   - By the way, sometimes the *"Nope, you can't"* answer is given, but it is still ignored by the OP, which seems to be refusing a "no" as an answer.
4. The question keeps being unanswered (meaning no answer is accepted, if any) until the end of time.

An example of this may be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25016442/3889449), which then generated [this related meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267993/3889449).
I'm excluding situations (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29537123/3889449)) where the OP understands that their problem hasn't got a solution and edits the question to make it clearer and solvable.

What should be done (by the community itself) in this kind of situation?

Comment: Questions like this usually should simply be closed.  "Can I do X" questions are answerable two ways--"yes" or "no".  You can't get much more useless than this.

Comment: @Won't It doesn't seem he's asking about "can I do X?" questions, but rather, say, someone asking how to do something that's just not possible, i.e, "How can I write a function that accepts some code and determines if that code will always finish executing?"  The answer to that question is, naturally, "It's provably impossible to write such a program."  It's a sensible (although poorly researched in my example) question that has a correct, well defined answer, (that answer being that there is no solution to the problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the OP accepts the answer or not.  We don't need the OP to accept an answer.  If the community feels that the answer is useful, upvotes communicate this just fine.

The OP *shouldn't* be editing the question to ask for something completely different after getting an answer.  Editing a question into a completely different question after getting an answer is an inappropriate edit; something that should be rolled back.

We don't want them to delete the question either.  It's an answered question that is contributing to the knowledge base of the site.  The only reason to delete it would be if nobody would ever want to know that the question has no solution (which, while possible, won't always be the case).  It's often useful to know that you can't Foo the Bar no matter what you do (particularly if backed up with solid reasoning/proof of why it is impossible).

Answer (score 4):

> What should be done (by the community itself) in this kind of situation?

Provide an answer to the question. Even if the question is couched as a "yes/no" question, the custom on SO (which should probably be adopted by other SE sites if they have not yet done so) is to answer the "yes" with an explanation of how to do it and the "no" with an explanation as to why it is impossible, and provide alternatives if there are ways to get the desired result by diverging from the parameters that were set in the question.

The reason you'll often see an "it is impossible" answer in a comment rather than as an actual answer is that it is easy for people who are not experts to have an *inkling* that "it is impossible" is probably true but they don't know the system well enough to be *absolutely certain* it is the case. Or they don't know how to explain the why, or how to do it in a different way.